# Manually creating Add Row Button in tabular form in APEX 4.1 giving error

Tags: button, row, oracle-apex, manual, tabular-form

I have created manual Add Row button on my tabular form in APEX 4.1. However, when I press ADD Row button the tabular form query is not refreshing. I have partial page refresh set on tabular form region.

The Add Row button submits the page.

The tabular form has union all query and the second part of the query has all corresponding null values for the columns and is getting data from Dual. It has where condition

where :REQUEST = 'ADD_ROWS' 
and connect by level <=1;

Issue.

When I put the above where clause the page is generated but the browser shows a warning at bottom and the details has following Error

Error : Object doesn't support this property or method".

Where I press Add Rows button, It reloads the page but no new row is created. I tried in Firefox also. Firefox didn't show any warning, but no row is created when Add Row button is pressed.

When I comment out the where condition in second part of the union all SQL statement no warning is generated, so I presume it is something to do with the where condition.

My Add Row functionality is based on following method explained by Denes in his Application

http://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=31517:170:9915790172855:::::

Please kindly provide your valuable inputs.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What validates this kind of setup actually? Do you do this because your new row needs default values? This kind of setup can be murderous. I'd not do it unless i really really have to. In 4.1 you even have tabular form validations on wizard generated tabular forms and there are other ways to generate a new row with default values. Not that i don't have manual tabforms though, but i try to avoid them.

Comment: What i meant, mainly, is that you should explain just a bit more about the what and why you need this so i can try and help

Comment: Thanks a lot Tom, but I was missing semi-colon at the end of the SQL, Once I put that it worked. I was trying to create Add Row button manually, instead of the standard built-in process. As I created manual tabular form, I needed this to create manually.